# Order by on String's substring in Linq

Tags: string, linq, sorting

I have a date field for which I convert the value of the database from datetime to string format("dd-MMM-yyyy"), I need to perform sorting this string date field, but seems like when I have been doing the sorting, it is working and checking only the date, not the month as well as not the year.
So when the data is in date format (database):

```
2012-01-29
2011-01-01
2013-03-28
```

So it is sorted like

```
2013-03-28
2012-01-29
2011-01-01
```

But it is sorted:
    29-Jan-2012
    28-Mar-2013
    01-Jan-2011

So I want to apply orderbydescending-> then by-> so on,
I need to split the string from end, is there a way around?
 I am doing:

```
List<c> lst=lst.OrderByDescending(d=>d.TDate.Substring(d.TDate.LastIndexOf('-').toList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this,

```
List<string> lst= new List<string>{"29-Jan-2012", "28-Mar-2013", "01-Jan-2011","2011-01-01","2013-03-28"};
lst.OrderByDescending(x=>DateTime.Parse(x));
```

in your sample it should be,

```
lst.OrderByDescending(x=>DateTime.Parse(x.TDate))
```

Answer (score 0):

Things are easier when you use dates. First I'd look at getting dates out of the database without converting to a string. If that fails you can do this...

```
lst.OrderByDescending(d=>DateTime.Parse(d.TDate))
```

Comment: I have been doing the same, but later when in session, the text is used as a string and then I need to do sorting in session, where the format is obviously string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order a string like a date, parse it to `DateTime`:

```
List<c> lst = lst
    .Select(x => new { Obj = x, Date = DateTime.Parse(x.TDate) })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
    .Select(x => x.Obj).ToList();
```

Even better, store a `DateTime` in the first place and convert it to a string at the very last place.

Comment: @ItiTyagi: I don't understand your comment.